# Python's XlsxWriter insert textbox into chart

Tags: python, excel, charts, textbox, xlsxwriter

I have already created a combined chart with column and line plot. The tricky part is to insert a textbox into the chart:
1. below X axis title
2. below legend.

I read the documentation and I found worksheet.insert_textbox(). However, I need something for a chart (if I understand documentation correctly, the above method works on a sheet, not on a chart).

I am using Anaconda Python (2.3.0) on Windows Vista 64bit.

```
result = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:/tmp/dev_excel.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# inserting image with 'xlsxwriter'
workbook = result.book

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
# Add the worksheet data to be plotted.
data = ['Aaaa', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 20, 10, 50]
worksheet.write_column('A1', data)

data = ['Bbbbb', 10, 40, 50, 20, 10, 50]
worksheet.write_column('B1', data)

data = ['Cccc', 110, 140, 150, 120, 110, 150]
worksheet.write_column('C1', data)

# Create a new column chart. This will use this as the primary chart.
column_chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

# Configure the data series for the primary chart.
column_chart.add_series({
    'name':       '=Sheet1!B1',
    'categories': '=Sheet1!A2:A7',
    'values':     '=Sheet1!B2:B7',
})

# Create a new column chart. This will use this as the secondary chart.
line_chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

# Configure the data series for the secondary chart.
line_chart.add_series({
    'name':       '=Sheet1!C1',
    'categories': '=Sheet1!A2:A7',
    'values':     '=Sheet1!C2:C7',
    'y2_axis':    True,
})

# Add a chart title and some axis labels.
# ...
column_chart.set_y2_axis({'name': 'Target length (mm)'})

# Combine the charts.
column_chart.combine(line_chart)

# Add a chart title and some axis labels. Note, this is done via the
# primary chart.
column_chart.set_title({ 'name': 'Combined chart - same Y axis'})
column_chart.set_x_axis({'name': 'Test number'})
column_chart.set_y_axis({'name': 'Sample length (mm)'})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet
worksheet.insert_chart('E2', column_chart)

workbook.close()

result.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

> if I understand documentation correctly, the above method works on a sheet, not on a chart

That is correct. Textboxes in charts aren't supported in XlsxWriter.

You can overlay a worksheet textbox over a chart but they will be two separate objects and will move independently of each other.

Comment: I had the same idea. However, we need to embed those boxes into the graph itself. So, the solution for now is to create text boxes outside of the graph and copy-paste their content manually into created text boxes (in Excel). Is there any chance for implementing this feature? Or you have more important stuff to do? I would like to avoid using Excel, if possible. So, this library is very handy for this (and I like how easy it is to use it).